# AdMob not working with IF statement?

Tags: if-statement, locale, admob, ads

This code doesn't work. I checked **displayLanguage** value. Value is right (**displayLanguage="Türkçe"**). But it doesn't work.

```
private void setAdvertisement()
{

Locale _locale = Locale.getDefault();
String displayLanguage = _locale.getDisplayLanguage();
if(displayLanguage == "Türkçe")
{
    // Create the adView
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "My Admob ID");

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"


    // Add the adView to it
    linearLayoutAdvertisement.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
}
```

But this code works fine:

```
private void setAdvertisement()
{
        // Create the adView
        adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "My Admob ID");

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"


        // Add the adView to it
        linearLayoutAdvertisement.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

}
```

I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an AdMob issue.  But try this:

```
if ("Türkçe".equals(displayLanguage)) {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. This worked for me:

```
if(Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("tr"))
    {
        ...
    }
```